# How to perform Looping Through List Items in SharePoint 2013 Designer Workflows?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-workflow

I am new to SharePoint. I'm creating a workflow in SharePoint 2013 in which I want to iterate a List using a loop.
How to perform looping through list items in SharePoint 2013 Designer Workflows?

Comment: What have you tried so far based off search engine queries?  It'll be easier to help you once we get more specific to your needs.  http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

I'm not aware that there's any out-of-box way to get a workflow to "loop through" all entries in a list, but you can try to make two workflows bouncing back to each other until all entries are updated, here is the detailed steps,

1. assuming that the list that we are working on is named `list_work`, in this list, create a column named e.g. `cargo`
2. define another list, name it e.g. `list_control`,

   - define a column named e.g. `listID`,
   - define a column named e.g. `cargo`,
   - create one entry in the list, set the `cargo` to a value.
3. define a workflow, name it e.g. `workflow_list_control`, which is triggered every time the entry in `list_control` is updated, and in this workflow,

   - search for an entry in the `list_work` where the `list_work.cargo` doesn't equal `list_control.cargo`
   - if any entry is found, update the entry of `list_work` and set the `list_work.cargo` with `list_control.cargo`, in order to trigger the `workflow_list_work` (see #4 below)
   - if no entry is found, stop this workflow.
4. define the workflow that needs to be run on the `list_work`, e.g. named `workflow_list_work`, make it's triggered every time the entry in `list_work` is updated, and in this workflow, make sure it updates the only entry in the `list_control` with the ID of the entry from `list_work` that is being modified, only to trigger the `workflow_list_control`. In this step, try to put a workflow step to wait and verify the ID is properly updated, in order to allow enough time for the previous `workflow_list_control` properly finishes.

Every time if a looping-through is necessary, modify the entry in `list_control` with a different value in the `cargo` field.

Also refer to [calculated-column-to-retrieve-total-number-of-id](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/101125/calculated-column-to-retrieve-total-number-of-id)

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in SharePoint 2013 (ONLY!) using the new "HTTP web service". The "trick" is to

1. Create a task that will call the HTTP Web Service and call ".../client.svc/web/lists/getbyid(`<List Guid>`)/items"
2. Return the (JSON) results in a (new in 2013 also!) "dictionary" variable
3. Use the "Get an Item from a Dictionary" action

   - "item by name or path" and enter "d/results"
   - select the "dictionary" variable (that you captured the results in)
   - output to another dictionary variable (call it "data")
4. Then get the count (for the loop) by using the action "Count Items in data" and output that to a variable (totalItems) to get the number of records

For the "loop" you will use the "Loop with condition"; use a variable called "index" and set it to 0. "Loop with condition" until "index < totalItems"

In the body of the loop:

1. "Get an item from a dictionary" use "item by name or path"
2. using string builder "d/results/(`<index>`)/". 
   The "Column Name to Retrieve" will be whatever column(s) you want to evaluate (like maybe "DueDate").

   *Note: You will have to use the "Static Name" of the column, which can be found by going to the Task List Settings and clicking the name of the column, then in the URL find the "Field=`<Name>`" portion.. It is that "`<Name>`" that you will use.*

---

I know this is very CRUDE maybe even bordering on "useless" for alot of users, but I felt I should at least attempt a quick reply. When I have more time, I will try to edit this and format my reply better. Although, I found this because of a similar need and since I figured out a way to accomplish what I was needing, I felt compelled to at least share it the best I could, in the limited time I had available. ;) So, maybe SOMEONE will find what I have attempted to describe, "useful". :)

Comment: I havn't tried it yet, but I hope your solution is still useful for Sharepoint Online?