# SharePoint Workflow variable is not recognized in O365 site

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, office365, sharepoint-online

I've created a Site Workflow of SharePoint 2013 Workflow type in O365 subsite of a site collection.
I use Call HTTP web service in workflow: screenshot of my workflow
http://www.image-share.com/ijpg-2992-17.html

To parse JSON results I need to use Variable:Index (Integer).

I've tried `d/results/([%Variable: Index%])/Title` as it is recommended in numerous blog posts ([example](http://www.wonderlaura.com/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=224)).
But Workflow gets Suspened with the following error:

> RequestorId: 8c3e172b-5da7-75d9-0000-000000000000. Details: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the workflow instance. Exception details: System.FormatException: The DynamicValue property 'd/results/([%Variable: Index%])/Title' was incorrectly formatted. at Microsoft.Activities.Dynamic.DynamicValueBuilder.PathSegmentFactory.Parse(String segmentText, String fullPathName) at Microsoft.Activities.Dynamic.DynamicValueBuilder.PathSegmentFactory.Create(String segment, PathSegment next, String path) at Microsoft.Activities.Dynamic.DynamicValueBuilder.PathSegmentFactory.Create(String path) at Microsoft.Activities.GetDynamicValueProperty`1.Execute(CodeActivityContext context) at System.Activities.CodeActivity`1.InternalExecute(ActivityInstance instance, ActivityExecutor executor, BookmarkManager bookmarkManager) at System.Activities.Runtime.ActivityExecutor.ExecuteActivityWorkItem.ExecuteBody(ActivityExecutor executor, BookmarkManager bookmarkManager, Location resultLocation) Exception from activity GetDynamicValueProperty Stage 2 Sequence Flowchart Sequence Email30Days.WorkflowXaml_3f207548_d246_4058_82b3_34acf1933b6f

If I use the same but with number (not variable) `d/results/(0)/Title` it works.

Please, let me know What I'm missing.

Comment: please review the following link http://goo.gl/Tj9vRG it may help

Comment: this article doesn't answer the main question - how to pass variables

Answer (score 0):

It seems there was a glitch in SharePoint Designer. When I opened SPD the next time, it started to resolve `[%Variable: Index%]` just fine.

I've also tried to add slash in the end of string "d/results/(`<index>`)/" (like in the [following article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25810296/how-to-perform-looping-through-list-items-in-sharepoint-2013-designer-workflows)) before I noticed the first time Index began to resolve, however I never added slash at the ending furthemore.

Answer (score 0):

Just FYI to whoever has similar issue, I noticed that in SPD - likely due to some quirk in copying text into string builder window from the web - if I type text manually or paste it, it doesn't seem to recognize it (same error occurs during workflow execution). But if you type into the window:

```
d/results(
```

then click **Add or Change Lookups** button and reference your variable, then finish typing the text:

```
)/YourPropertyName
```

- then it all works well.